# JSFiddle Code working, but not working when in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

My [JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/qfygM/415/) works perfectly within the workspace.  Just trying to do a simply show/hide of a menu that has children:

```
$('#menu-product-categories .sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default

$('#menu-product-categories li a').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').children().length !== 0) {     
        event.preventDefault();
    }
$(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

However, when I take that same exact code and put it into my wordpress site, it does not function.  I'm adding the jquery to the header of the site exactly how it is done within the JSFiddle, and I directly copy/pasted the menu structure from my wordpress site.  I don't see how this can happen?  Any advice would be helpful

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a browsers finds a script tag, it executes the content directly. Because you put this code into your header page, this is executed **before** the html is generated, so before your menu finally exists.

You have two solutions :

1. Place your script tag at the end of the page, after your menu declaration
2. Better way : execute your script when page has finished loading :

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $('#menu-product-categories .sub-menu').hide(); //Hide children by default

       $('#menu-product-categories li a').click(function(event){
           if ($(this).next('ul.sub-menu').children().length !== 0) {     
               event.preventDefault();
           }
       $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle('slow');
       });
   });
   ```

`ready` is an event, fired when all the DOM has been fully loaded.

Corresponding jQuery documentation : http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Hi there.  Thank you very much for your response.  I was playing around with the JSFiddle, the original code, and when I changed to wrap the code in the <head> on the left side I noticed the script didn't work.  Just like you said! I then added the .ready event and chose to wrap it in the head, and it worked in the JSFiddle!  I did this same thing in my wordpress site, however, and still no luck! IF you'll see my screenshot - http://postimg.org/image/uqiwsro79/ for a better look.  Thanks for your help again Edit: I also placed this script before the closing </body> tag

Comment: If you place your code inside a `ready` handler, you should put it in the <head> section, this is better. Do you get javascript errors ? BTW, why surrounding your code into CDATA section ? Are you using XHTML ? Here is a good article about it : http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm

Comment: Jsut thinking about it : your jquery is probably in noconflict mode. The thing is that the `$` sign can be used by other javascript frameworks : to prevent conflicts, the `jQuery.noConflict()` method allows to unbind jquery object from `$` sign. In this case, you should replace the first line of the code i posted by : `jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {`